# How to download older version of an app for older devices?

Tags: ios, itunes, ipad, youtube

Long story short, I recently deleted the Google YouTube app off my iPad 1 in hopes to fix some weird behavior. I planned to reinstall it right after, but to my dismay, it wouldn't let me download it from the purchased section. I'm aware that if an app no longer supports your ios version, but it used to, you can go to the purchased section of the store and attempt to download it. A warning would appear that says you can download the last supported version of the app for your device.

Well, the YouTube app is completely grayed out. Despite the fact I *had* a supported version of Google's YouTube app on my iPad 1 just a few days ago, I can no longer download it off the appstore. A few other apps can still redownload older versions just fine, but the YouTube app is still unavailable. This is really all I used the iPad 1 for, so without YouTube it's just kind of useless.

Any help as to what to try is appreciated. I have the up to date version of iTunes, 12.7.4, for a 64bit windows system. If there's any trick I can use to get the app back on the iPad 1, I'll gladly try it.

If Apple/Google removed the older versions of their apps of the store entirely, is there any other way to get a hold of the older app?

Comment: iTunes 12.7.4 doesn't have the iTunes App Store for iOS built in. You can try installing the last supported version of iTunes (iTunes 12.6.4) with App Store built in by downloading it from [here](https://support.apple.com/kb/HT208079)

Comment: What happens if you search the App Store **ON** your iPad? If it doesn't show up it may be that Google removed the old app for previous iOS versions